# How to use docker to run sqli-labs(a web application) on Windows?

Tags: docker

I try to use Docker to run sqli-labs, I use the command:

```
docker pull acgpiano/sqli-labs
```

to pull the images, and after I use the command:

```
docker run -dt --name sqli -p 80:80 --rm acgpiano/sqli-labs
```

I visit the http://localhost, but my browser shows me 404..
here is the screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZG8C.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CteL.png)

Why I can not get the right page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the page is not accessible on your machines localhost but on your containers localhost.

You can access it if you go to localhost inside your container or on your machines IP.

EDIT:

How to access localhost inside the container:

```
# I ran the same commands as you
docker pull acgpiano/sqli-labs
docker run -dt --name sqli -p 80:80 --rm acgpiano/sqli-labs
# First get the container id with 
docker ps -a
# I got this output:
# CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                          NAMES
# d91384617370        acgpiano/sqli-labs   "/run.sh"           3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 3306/tcp   sqli

# Then execute bash command as root for this container id
docker exec -it -u root d91384617370 bash

# Inside the container update apt-get and get curl (or wget)
apt-get update -y
apt-get install curl -y

# Go to localhost - the page will be printed in your terminal
curl localhost
```

How to access it in windows 10 (tested with Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40), I'm using powershell and docker for windows

```
docker pull acgpiano/sqli-labs
docker run -dt --name sqli -p 80:80 --rm acgpiano/sqli-labs

# In powershell get the hostname - copy it to your browser - http://your_hostname or just your_hostname
hostname
# Or run ipconfig to find your IP - copy it to your browser http://your_ip or your_ip
ipconfig | findstr [0-9].\.
```

I would also recommend [this](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/) example from the docs, great way to get started.

Comment: what should I do to get the right page on my Windows machine?

Comment: I've edited my answer with additional information and also tested the solution and provided some sample outputs. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks! I copy the ip address of container to my FireFox browser in Windows and I got the page, but I'm confused why I can't get the page in the edge browser with the same ip address.

Comment: I've just tried it in Edge and the only difference with Firefox was that I had to write "http://my_hostname" in Firefox it works with or without the "http://". I don't use Edge so I can't help you more about that.
If my answer helped you and answered your question, please remember to accept it as the correct answer.

Comment: "Because the page is not accessible on your machines localhost but on your containers localhost" but thats what the port binding is for?? (-p 80:80)