# Docker port mapping is not working on windows 10

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I am new to docker. I am trying to get a simple node app running on docker. However I am facing an issue with the docker port publish.

[Docker version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3Qj3.png) - 18.03.0-ce, build 0520e24302

My simple app code:

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');

// Constants
const PORT = 8081;
const HOST = '0.0.0.0';

// App
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello world\n');
});

app.listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log(`Running on http://${HOST}:${PORT}`);
```

My docker file:

```
FROM node:carbon

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8081

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

[My docker ps output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z95Sk.png) - 0.0.0.0:8080->8081/tcp, loving hugle

[Output from curl command from my local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KiAjT.png) - Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On Windows, Linux containers are created inside a virtual machine that runs on Windows host OS. This virtual machine gets assigned an IP. While doing the curl, you should use this IP instead of `localhost`. Here, `localhost` means the Windows host and not the virtual machine that we intend to hit on the port 8080.

To know the IP assigned to the virtual machine, run the `docker-machine ls` command. You will get output similar to the following:

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME      ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                         SWARM   DOCKER        ERRORS
default   *        virtualbox   Running   tcp://192.168.99.100:2376           v18.05.0-ce
```

Note the IP in the above command output under `URL` -- it would be a different IP when you run the command on your machine. Then use it to do the curl:

```
curl -i 192.168.99.100:8080
```

Comment: docker-machine ls is not working

Answer (score 20):

It is 2020, and docker treats these commands differently:

`docker run -p 3000:80 my_image` (Correct format; port option has to come before image name.)

`docker run my_image -p 3000:80` (Wrong format; docker will not notify you, and will silently fail port publishing.)

Hopefully this helps someone (or me, next time I work with docker xD)

Comment: I believe with the second format, what docker is doing is passing the parameters "-p 3000:80" through as extra parameters to the entrypoint of your container.  That's why it fails silently - the command is syntactically valid.  See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint

Comment: @RobertRendell You are probably right, thanks for the info :)

Comment: This saved me days! I wonder when the latter format will be useful

Answer (score -1):

Your port mapping is 8080-8081 and you're trying to connect to localhost:8080 on your windows machine.

You need to go inside your docker container and curl to localhost:8081 or from your windows machine curl to your hostname:8080.

You can get your hostname in windows running

```
hostname
curl your_hostname:8080
```

You can get get inside your docker container using its id or name (on your picture it's called loving_hugle) and then curling to localhost

```
docker exec -it loving_hugle bash
curl localhost:8081
```

Comment: Thank you  for your quick answer, I was able the get curl localhost:8081 working within the docker container. However; it is still doesn't work even I did curl your_hostname:8080 on my window machine.

Comment: So it's working from inside your container? And are you sure you got your hostname with the hostname command and used that in your curl command?

Comment: yes correct. however; It doesn't work when I try to do curl within my windows machine(outside of the container) And yes I used my hostname I got from the hostname command.

Comment: That's strange, can you please read my answer here and let me know if that works - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50812536/how-to-use-docker-to-run-sqli-labsa-web-application-on-windows/50812944#50812944

Comment: I tried both using ip and hostname. Still no luck :(. If I just run "node" locally, it works properly. Just that I am not able to expose it from my container to my outside windows properly.

Comment: Could you try running "docker run -d -p 80:80 nginx" - it's a small image of a reverse proxy. And once its started check if curl your_hostname or curl your_hostname:80 connects - you should get "Welcome to nginx!..." page.

Comment: I tried it as well. I cannot connect to the port 80 either.

Comment: I have a few ideas, but am mostly guessing...
Are you running docker for windows or are you using virtual box/vmware etc. and on that a linux where you have installed docker?
If you're using docker for windows - are you using proxies? Did you allow docker as an exception in your firewall, when prompted?