# Docker: Not able to access running server api

Tags: docker

I created docker image form my spring boot application.

My Dockerfile looks like this :

```
FROM java:8
EXPOSE 8080
COPY ./sample-app-3.2.1.war sample-app-3.2.1.war
CMD ["java","-jar", "sample-app-3.2.1.war"]
```

I am able to create and run the docker image on server with below command:

```
to build image:
sudo docker build -f Dockerfile -t app:1.0 .

to run image:
sudo docker run -p 8080:8080 app:1.0
```

but I am not able to access api on my local machine browser.

without docker its working perfectly

I am trying like this :-

- suppose server ip is : A.B.C.D
- api mapping : api/test
- http://A.B.C.D:8080/api/test

Comment: the ip A.B.C.D supposed to be your docker host ip

Comment: I checked the running container IP address and try with that also but not working

Comment: `docker exec -it container_name sh -c "curl localhost:8080` can you verify this command?

Comment: I tried that command on server terminal , that giving expected response

Answer (score 0):

You need to expose your java application to **0.0.0.0** to listen to all interfaces. Not just localhost.

If your on windows look here [Docker port mapping is not working on windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890981/docker-port-mapping-is-not-working-on-windows-10)